# Authenticating a client to a server

Tags: authentication, encryption, client-server, client

I have a small device that contains a client program which communicates with a server over the internet. Pretty standard stuff.

I have a requirement that the server be able to authenticate messages coming from the device, meaning that all communications from the device be from the authentic client and not from some impostor. It's assumed that an attacker can reverse engineer the client and also load his own programs onto the device.

I'm questioning whether this is even possible. I could certainly load a client certificate into the client, but an attacker could get to this and use it himself. The cost of the device must remain low, so no fancy hardware tricks. Any ideas on how I could do this?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the device, and what kind of abuse you are talking about, you could use a scheme that needs some kind of **activation**. Like entering a **master key** into **memory only** - so its lost if power is lost - a technic used on some crypto cards.

A way to counter **stolen devices** could involve some kind of **lease of keys** that needs **renewal** on a regular basic **by specifying a secret**.

A way to counter an **imitation/copy** could be to works with a **common state** between the client and server that **keeps changing**. Like negotiating new encryption keys regularly.

Answer (score 0):

We use a similar thing with our apps and web services. We call it ApiValidation where the client in each request to the service adds a header called ApiID which the server can decode to see if the client is authorized or not.

Comment: How do you ensure that the ApiID is not caught and misused by an attacker?

Comment: We have security apart from the ApiID which is also baked into the app. The client and server communication is based on RSA+AES Encryption. So it is a combination of ApiID, AES and RSA Encryption which we use for all of that. You can have a look at [MobileIT Website](http://www.mobileit.co.za) to get a better picture

Comment: But somehow the client needs to know its credentials - whether it's a private key, a certificate, a password, an API ID or whatever. How do you secure that?

Comment: The way the ApiID works is as follows: We generate a unique GUID per app and call it the APPID. This AppID is given to the app developer and he can hardcode that into his app. The app then generates a unique instanceID which is specific to the device. It then generates an ApiID from the two GUID's using a predefined function which is then sent to the server. The client also generates an AES key per launch and encrypts it with the RSA public key which is again given to the app developer at the start of the project. On the server side we can decode the ApiID and get RSA key and verify AES key

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. What I still do not understand is: How do you protect the data on the client from being stolen by an attacker? I suppose that by getting a device and doing some reverse-engineering it should be possible to get the IDs, isn't it?

Comment: I do get your point. We obfuscate the app's before installation first of all. We do not leave this data in a config file but it is in the compiled code.

Comment: Okay, so one might say that it comes down security by obscurity (it all depends on the quality of obfuscating and the effort needed for reverse engineering). This may be a "okay" solution, but it's far from perfect. IMHO the question is if we can raise the bar even higher than this, and I think that this conforms with the OP when he wrote: *It's assumed that an attacker can reverse engineer*. What do you think?

Comment: From my experience everything can be hacked and reverse engineered. The best you can do as a developer is to make sure how tedious you can make the process of breaking security keys and obfuscation. Even the most secure encryption algorithm does not guarantee an attack all it shows is that the time taken to find the key in an ideal scenario will be more.

Comment: This is actually not true. There are (proven) algorithms that can not be broken if applied correctly, such as OTP.